# Python concat string with list

Tags: python, list

I wanted to build a string from a list.

I used the string.join() command, but if I have :

```
['hello', 'good', 'morning']
```

I get : `hellogoodmorning`

Is there a method that allows me to put a space between every word ? (without the need to write a for loop)

kind regards.

Comment: Why not show exactly how you "used the string.join() command"?

Comment: I agree with @KarlKnechtel, adding the (minimal) code that leads to the unwanted results, helps a lot. Here I guess, the code was `''.join(['hello', 'good', 'morning'])`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

All you need to do is add the space in front of join.

```
 ' '.join(list)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
>>> ' '.join(['hello', 'good', 'morning'])
'hello good morning'
```

The standard and best way to join a list of strings. I cannot think of anything better than this one.

Answer (score 6):

This does what you want:

```
" ".join(['hello', 'good', 'morning'])
```

Generally, when you are calling `join()` on some string you use `" "` to specify the separator between the list elements.

Answer (score 4):

`' '.join(...)` is the easiest way as others have mentioned.  And in fact it is the preferred way to do this in all cases (even if you are joining with no padding, just use `''.join(...)`).

While it still has some useful functions... most of the `string` modules functions have been made methods on the str type/object.

You can find the full list of deprecated string-functions (including `join`) in the [Deprecated string functions](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions) section of the python docs.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> " ".join(['hello', "good", "morning"])
'hello good morning'
```

or you can use the `string.join()` function, which uses a single space as the default separator.

```
>>> help(string.join)
Help on function join in module string:

join(words, sep=' ')
    join(list [,sep]) -> string

    Return a string composed of the words in list, with
    intervening occurrences of sep.  The default separator is a
    single space.
```

example:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.join(['hello', "good", "morning"])
'hello good morning'
```