# How to insert space after every element in a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list 'decrypted_characters' that looks like this

> ['mathematician', 'to', 'present', 'a', 'proof', 'of', 'the', 'sensitivity']

I want it to look like a paragraph so I tried

```
decrypted_word = ''.join(decrypted_characters)
```

and when I print it looks like

> mathematiciantopresentaproofofthesensitivity

How to add spaces after each element so that it looks like sentence? I want it to look like

> mathematician to present a proof of the sensitivity

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Comment: So many dupes, pick one: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings), [here], [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546245/python-concat-string-with-list), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566527/concatenate-python-string-from-list-entries) etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python concat string with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546245/python-concat-string-with-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join):

```py
In [4]: ' '.join(['mathematician', 'to', 'present', 'a', 'proof', 'of', 'the', 'sensitivity'])

Out[4]: 'mathematician to present a proof of the sensitivity'
```

Comment: What if the list is very long?

Comment: You can use the spread operator, decrypted_word = ' '.join([...decrypted_characters])  this will spread your array out, and the above suggestion should work nicely

Answer (score 1):

```
decrypted_characters = ['mathematician', 'to', 'present', 'a', 'proof', 'of', 'the', 'sensitivity']
decrypted_word = ' '.join(decrypted_characters)
print(decrypted_word)
```

Try this out.

Comment: How is this different than the existing answer?

Comment: @cricket_007 this is close enough but I am just keeping same format with minimum change to that guy who asked question get it correctly with minimum effort.